# How can I set the text of a label

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I've got a usercontrol that I want to put in a FixedDocument, but before I do that I need to change the text of a label.  I think I need to use Dependency Properties.

Here's the simplified XAML.

```
<UserControl x:Class="PrinterTest.TestControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding LabelCaption}"
               Height="24" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Name="lblCaption"     
               Width="140" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the codebehind

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl
{
    public TestControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public readonly static DependencyProperty 
        LabelCaptionDP = DependencyProperty.Register("LabelCaption",
                                                     typeof(string), 
                                                     typeof(TestControl),
                                                     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("no data"));

    public string LabelCaption
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelCaptionDP); }
        set { SetValue(LabelCaptionDP, value); }
    }
```

In the calling bit I instantiate by `TestControl myControl = new TestControl();`

What am I doing wrong, because I can't access the properties in the new copy of the control?   Thank you!

Comment: Thanks LPL - made those naming convention changes.

In my calling code I tried 
     UserControl TestControl = new TestControl();

            (TestControl)TestControl.LabelCaptionProperty = "Test";

But I get a System.Windows.Controls.UserControl does not contain a definition for LabelCaptionProperty and I can't see anything in Intellisense.  What stupid thing am I doing?

Answer (score 2):

Change `LabelCaptionDP` to `LabelCaptionProperty`.

From [Dependency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx#back_dependency_properties):

> The naming convention of the property and its backing
>   DependencyProperty field is important. The name of the field is always
>   the name of the property, with the suffix Property appended. For more
>   information about this convention and the reasons for it, see Custom
>   Dependency Properties.

Please read about *Dependency Property Name Conventions* in [Custom Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx#checklist).

Comment: Thanks LPL - made those naming convention changes. In my calling code I tried UserControl TestControl = new TestControl(); (TestControl)TestControl.LabelCaptionProperty = "Test"; But I get a System.Windows.Controls.UserControl does not contain a definition for LabelCaptionProperty and I can't see anything in Intellisense. What stupid thing am I doing?

Comment: For this use the Back CLR Property: `((TestControl)TestControl).LabelCaption = "Test";`.

Comment: Thank you.  Syntax sorted!  This is my first essay into the joys of WPF.  Daresay I might get the hang of it once my textbooks arrive.
Now all I have to do is wrestle with my grid outlines. Thanks again for relieving me of my frustration.