# WPF Data Binding- Binding Obj. inside Obj. to UserControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have 2 user controls in `MainWindow.xaml`, They are `SidePannel` and `Description`. I am passing an `DictionaryModel` Object. In the `DictionaryModel` object there is a Collection of `Words` and Another object called `SidePannelModel`. In the `SidePannelModel` there is another collection of `Words` and a string property.

```
DictionaryModel

public class DictionaryModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public SidePannelModel SideModel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<WordModel> Language2 { get; set; }

    public void ToggleLanguage()
    {
        var temp = this.Language2;
        this.Language2 = this.SideModel.Language1;
        this.SideModel.Language1 = temp;

        OnPropertyChanged("DictionaryChanged");
    }


    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

SidePannelModel

public class SidePannelModel
{
    public IEnumerable<WordModel> Language1 { get; set; }
    public string SearchWord { get; set; }
}
```

I am passing the DictionaryModel to DataContext in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private DictionaryModel dictionary;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dictionary = new DictionaryModel
            {
                    SideModel = new SidePannelModel {
                    SearchWord=null,
                    Language1 = new List<WordModel>() 
                    { 
                        new WordModel() { Word = "Test1" }
                        , new WordModel() { Word = "Test2" }
                        , new WordModel() { Word = "Test3" }
                        , new WordModel() { Word = "Test4" }
                        , new WordModel() { Word = "Test5" }
                        , new WordModel() { Word = "Test6" }
                        , new WordModel() { Word = "Test7" }
                        , new WordModel() { Word = "Test8" }
                        , new WordModel() { Word = "Test9" }
                        , new WordModel() { Word = "Test10" }

                    } as IEnumerable<WordModel>
                },


                Language2 = new List<WordModel>() 
                { 
                    new WordModel() { Word = "Test1" }
                    , new WordModel() { Word = "Test2" }
                    , new WordModel() { Word = "Test3" }
                    , new WordModel() { Word = "Test4" }
                    , new WordModel() { Word = "Test5" }
                    , new WordModel() { Word = "kkkkk" }
                    , new WordModel() { Word = "Test7" }
                    , new WordModel() { Word = "Test8" }
                    , new WordModel() { Word = "Test9" }
                    , new WordModel() { Word = "Test10" }

                } as IEnumerable<WordModel>,

            };

            this.DataContext = dictionary;
        }
     }
```

This is how I pass the Collection of `Words` and the `SidePannelModel` to the user controllers in the `ManiWindow.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="ThaiDictionary.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sidePanel="clr-namespace:ThaiDictionary"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="619">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"
       x:Key="toggleButtonStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Thai to English" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="English to Thai" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Margin="0,0,2,0">

    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Menu IsMainMenu="True" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Edit" />
            <MenuItem Header="_View" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Window" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Help" />
        </Menu>
        <StatusBar Height="22" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
        <sidePanel:SidePanel SideModel="{Binding SidePModel, Mode=TwoWay}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="540" Margin="5,5,5,1" Width="196"/>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="False" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="150" Style="{StaticResource toggleButtonStyle}" Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_Unchecked">
            </ToggleButton>
            <sidePanel:Description DockPanel.Dock="Top" WordsList2="{Binding Language2, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </DockPanel>

    </DockPanel>

</Grid>
```

`SideModel` is defined in the `SidePannel.xaml.cs`.

```
    public partial class SidePanel : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty SideModelProperty;


    static SidePanel()
    {
        SideModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SideModel", typeof(SidePannelModel), typeof(SidePanel)); 
    }

    public SidePanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    public SidePannelModel SideModel 
    {
         get
        {
            return (SidePannelModel)GetValue(SideModelProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SideModelProperty, value);
        }
    }

}
```

But the `SidePanel` controller is not loaded with the `Word`s I am expecting.

appropriate part of `SidePanel.xaml` is given below.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ThaiDictionary.SidePanel"
         x:Name="SidePannelController"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:l="clr-namespace:ThaiDictionary"
         mc:Ignorable="d" MinHeight="300" MinWidth="300" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Azure">
<UserControl.Resources>

</UserControl.Resources>

<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" DataContext="{Binding SidePModel}">
    <l:SearchTextBox SearchEventTimeDelay="00:00:02.00"  Text="{Binding  ElementName= SidePannelController,  Path= SearchWord, Mode=TwoWay}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  Search="SearchTextBox_Search" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Bisque"/>
    <ListBox Name="LeftSidePnel1" ItemsSource="{Binding  ElementName= SidePannelController,  Path= Language1, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource WordTemplate}" MinHeight="266" Height="auto" >
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="WordTemplate">
                <Label Content="{Binding Word}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

But when I run the project I can not see the words loaded in to the Sidepanel usercontrol. What is wrong with this code. I can not find a way out here. Can you give me some quick help.

Edit:

I have followed the naming conventions and changed the `SidePannel.xaml.cs`.

Binding error:

```
 System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=SidePanelController'. BindingExpression:Path=SearchWord; DataItem=null; target element is 'SearchTextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=SidePanelController'. BindingExpression:Path=Language1; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListBox' (Name='LeftSidePnel1'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
```

I have added the full SidePanel.xaml and I have changed the ElementName to SidePannelController as in the xaml file. But it still not getting loading the words

New Edit:

```
    System.Windows.Data Information: 41 : BindingExpression path error: 'SearchWord' property not found for 'object' because data item is null.  This could happen because the data provider has not produced any data yet. BindingExpression:Path=SideModel.SearchWord; DataItem='SidePanel' (Name='SidePannelController'); target element is 'SearchTextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=SideModel.SearchWord; DataItem='SidePanel' (Name='SidePannelController'); target element is 'SearchTextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=SideModel.SearchWord; DataItem='SidePanel' (Name='SidePannelController'); target element is 'SearchTextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=SideModel.SearchWord; DataItem='SidePanel' (Name='SidePannelController'); target element is 'SearchTextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 41 : BindingExpression path error: 'Language1' property not found for 'object' because data item is null.  This could happen because the data provider has not produced any data yet. BindingExpression:Path=SideModel.Language1; DataItem='SidePanel' (Name='SidePannelController'); target element is 'ListBox' (Name='LeftSidePnel1'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=SideModel.Language1; DataItem='SidePanel' (Name='SidePannelController'); target element is 'ListBox' (Name='LeftSidePnel1'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=SideModel.Language1; DataItem='SidePanel' (Name='SidePannelController'); target element is 'ListBox' (Name='LeftSidePnel1'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe all you have to do is correcting your DependencyProperty declaration because of Dependency Property Name Conventions. Please see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16404640/620360).

Comment: @LPL I have followed the naming conventions properly but the problem is the same.

Comment: Are you getting any binding errors in your `Output` window? Also, you're binding to an element named `SidePannelController2` - can you show the full XAML for where that control is and where the `SidePanel` `UserControl` referencing it is? I suspect your problem may be that the binding can't find an element named `SidePannelController2` further up the VisualTree from your `SidePanel`

Comment: @Rachel I have added the full XAML. Changed the ElementName as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Language1` and `SearchWord` are not properties on your `UserControl`, they're properties on your `UserControl.SideModel` property.

So change your bindings to include `SideModel` in your `Path` property, so it correctly binds to `SidePannelController.SideModel.Language1` (or `SearchWord`), like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=SidePannelController, Path=SideModel.Language1}"
```

But I suspect you're not showing your actual XAML, because your binding error says *"Cannot find source for binding"*, which means it can't find an element named `SidePannelController` in the `VisualTree` (since `ElementName` specifies the source to use for the binding).

If that's the case, you can try using a `RelativeSource` binding to find the `UserControl` instead of `ElementName`

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SideModel.Language1,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type l:SidePanel}}"
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Problem solved, One more thing, Even though the words are loaded to the sidepannel, The out put window still shows a binding error. as shown in the new Edit.Do you know what causes this problem?

Comment: @Diode You get a binding error anytime a binding tries to evaluate to a value and fails. There are many reasons it could be failing, however the most common is that the `DataContext` (data item) is incorrect. I wrote a SO answer recently about [debugging WPF binding errors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14523290/302677) that you may find useful. To summarize, break up your error by the colons/semicolons, and read it backwards to understand the exact location of the error and problem.

Comment: Wow thank you for a very constructive and detailed and dedicated answer. Appreciate a lot(Up Vote + Correct Answer + Up vote for related answer), Hope you give some help on WPF in the future as well. :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what DictionaryModel is.

Maybe a typo, but it's possible you have an extra `},` in MainWindow.xaml.cs right before:

`Language2 = new List<WordModel>()`

That would mean that `Language2` is not a member of `dictionary.SideModel`, but instead is another, separate element of the collection (a sibling property of SideModel?)

However, in MainWindow.xaml, you are Binding to Language2 *inside* of a binding to SideModel.  Since Language2 isn't a child of SideModel, XAML can't resolve the binding.

Comment: No it is not a typo, I have added the DictionaryModel. :)