# Module not rendering

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, module, prism

In my application i'm trying to load the main module trough code. Everything works up to the point of rendering and i have NO clue why it isn't rendering. The content has the right values and everything.. My guess is that something went wibbly wobbly and I seem to be missing it.

Control that holds the view

```
[ContentPropertyAttribute("ContentView")]
public class ContentControlExtened : ContentControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Type",
            typeof(Type),
            typeof(ContentControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, ContentTypeChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentViewProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register(
             "View",
             typeof(FrameworkElement),
             typeof(ContentControl),
             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, ContentViewChanged));

    private static void ContentViewChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ContentControlExtened()
    {
        this.Loaded += ContentControlLoaded;
    }

    private void ContentControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.LoadContent();
    }

    private void LoadContent()
    {
        UserControl u = null;

        if (Type != null)
        {
            u = (UserControl)ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(this.Type);
        }
        u.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 255));
        this.View = u;
    }

    public Type Type
    {
        get { return (Type)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public FrameworkElement View
    {
        get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ContentProperty, value);
        }
    }
    }
```

Method in shell to load the main view of the given moduleInfo

```
        private void OpenMainView(ModuleInfo module)
    {
        Type moduleType = Type.GetType(module.ModuleType);
        var moduleMainViewType = moduleType.Assembly.GetType(moduleType.Namespace + ".Views.MainView");
        this.ContentHolder.MainContent.Type = moduleMainViewType;
    }
```

The contructor of the mainview is straight forward. Just standard control InitializeComponent() and Datacontext is being set trough the servicelocator.

Comment: `Getter` and `Setter` for you DP's is missing.

Comment: They are there just didn't bother posting them because thats not the problem :)

Comment: What's `ContentType`? I guess something is wrong with your DP's.

Comment: Hang on ill post the entire file

Comment: Please see my answer [about Dependency Property Name Conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16404640/620360).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public FrameworkElement View
{
    get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ContentProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Here you are getting and setting the `ContentProperty`. It should be `ContentViewProperty`.

Comment: Yes true lol kinda fail but the module is still not rendering